# Why wont apk files download

Tags: apk

[image]
I used to be able to install apk files on my phone before I factory reset it and now it does not work
I have a sony m5

Answer (score 1):

In your settings there is an option to allow APKs from unknown locations. This is under Security for me, can't be sure where yours is but it will be there. A factory reset most likely returned it to the default off state.

Comment: I cant find it if you are talking about being able to download apk from the web i can do that i just cant install them onto my phone

Comment: Yes. By default, Android will not allow you to just install any APK that is not from the Play Store. You'll need to change that in the settings.

Comment: This guide explains it for you M5

Comment: Forgot the link! http://support.sonymobile.com/global-en/xperiam5/userguide/Downloading-applications-from-other-sources/